# por que cuando una computadora se conecta a mi red de internet las demás computadoras fallan su conexión?

Tags: redes, router

Buenos días, tengo un problema y nose cual sea la razón, les comento cuando conecto todas las computadoras a una mismo modem fallan pensé que era problema del proveedor, pero vinieron muchas veces y seguía igual, entonces intentando ver cual era el problema revisando los ip, desconecte una computadora de la red y se soluciono todas las computadoras iban rápido,y de ahí volví conectar la computadora y de nuevo todas fallaron es decir la conexión era muy lenta y se iba por ratos, en decir solo cuando desconecto esa computadora las demás están bien pero si la conecto falla la conexión
pdt: ya vi el problema de las ip cruzadas y no es ese el problema

Comment: Pudieras tener un conflicto de IP o nombre de equipo en la red. Chequea eso.

Comment: ¿Tienes algún pool de conexiones para el dhcp? No me queda del todo claro si es una máquina en concreto la que te da el error o es al conectar el dispositivo n+1. De ser una máquina en concreto, ¿has comprobado que esté limpia? Que no tenga ningún software malicioso corriendo.  Creo que faltan muchos datos para poder dar con una solución (operativos,  tarjetas, etc.).  Intenta explicarnos un poco más las pruebas que has llevado a cabo también y los resultados obtenidos. .

Comment: solo he comprobado que los ip´s no se estén cruzado , no se que otro diagnostico puedo hacer.. me puedes a decir que otro diagnostico y como hacerlo, si solo cuando conecto esa computadora me falla la conexión en las demás, y si la desconecto todo esta normal

Answer (score 0):

Puedes comprobar lo siguiente:

- Que la computadora que hace fallar a todas las demás no tenga una segunda dirección IP, que coincida con la del módem (dependiendo cual sea el sistema operativo de esa computadora, una segunda dirección IP puede no estar visible a primera vista)
- Revisa que la computadora que hace fallar a todas las demás no tenga un virus (malware, troyano, etc.); si tuviera un programa malicioso que intenta propagarse o usar tu computadora para hacer [ataques de negación de servicio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_de_denegaci%C3%B3n_de_servicio) puede saturar la conexión, y por ello al conectarla hace que el resto falle. Una forma de verificar esto puede ser conectarla sólo a ella al módem e intentar ver las estadísticas de la conexión cuando la PC esta en reposo: si esta siendo usada como *zombie* o intenta agresivamente propagarse verás un nivel de tráfico alto e inexplicable)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes revisar que todas las computadoras, en especial la computadora que tiene el problema tengan una configuración DHCP u "obtener ip automáticamente", caso contrario revisar que la computadora del conflicto no tenga algún virus, malware, o algún programa que te esté consumiendo el ancho de banda (en caso de ser Windows 10 revisa que no esté corriendo el proceso Windows Update), puedes ver esto en el administrador de tareas. Suerte!